# Presto unable to create injector with localfile connector

Tags: presto

I am using presto-server-0.149 on macOS 10.11. Just for testing purpose, I run a single node and everything is okay. When I add  `etc/catalog/localfile.properties` with:

```
connector.name=localfile
presto-logs.http-request-log-location=/var/log/apache2/access_log
```

I get the following error:

```
2016-07-04T12:02:45.435-0700    INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
2016-07-04T12:02:45.435-0700    INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup complete. System ready.
2016-07-04T12:02:45.436-0700    INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager -- Added catalog jmx using connector jmx --
2016-07-04T12:02:45.436-0700    INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager -- Loading catalog etc/catalog/localfile.properties --
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    INFO    main    Bootstrap   PROPERTY                               DEFAULT                   RUNTIME                   DESCRIPTION
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    INFO    main    Bootstrap   presto-logs.http-request-log.pattern   null                      null                      If log location is a directory this glob is used to match the file names in the directory
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    INFO    main    Bootstrap   presto-logs.http-request-log.location  var/log/http-request.log  var/log/http-request.log  Directory or file where http request logs are written
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    INFO    main    Bootstrap   
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    WARN    main    Bootstrap   UNUSED PROPERTIES
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    WARN    main    Bootstrap   presto-logs.http-request-log-location=/var/log/apache2/access_log
2016-07-04T12:02:45.797-0700    WARN    main    Bootstrap   
2016-07-04T12:02:45.989-0700    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'presto-logs.http-request-log-location=/var/log/apache2/access_log' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:235)

1 error
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'presto-logs.http-request-log-location=/var/log/apache2/access_log' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:235)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:242)
    at com.facebook.presto.localfile.LocalFileConnectorFactory.create(LocalFileConnectorFactory.java:64)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnector(ConnectorManager.java:315)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.addCatalogConnector(ConnectorManager.java:169)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:162)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:148)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalog(CatalogManager.java:99)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalogs(CatalogManager.java:77)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:115)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:63)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Dain Sundstrom's answer below, I was able to fix my problem. It turned out that the fb documentation for [Local File Connector](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/localfile.html) is incorrect. And since I needed to get something to feed Presto to test the localfile connector, I changed the config filepath to Presto's own request log:

```
presto-logs.http-request-log.location=/var/presto/data/var/log/http-request.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the configuration property.  It should be:

```
presto-logs.http-request-log.location=/var/log/apache2/access_log
```

Also, this connector can only process the http log format created by Presto itself, so you would need to reconfigure your Apache2 server to output the same format.

Comment: Thanks Dain. So it means the docs have a typo too because I cut and pasted that stuff right out of them at http://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/localfile.html. Maybe you can let them know? Where do I find which format PrestoDB is using. I can't find anywhere where this requirement is described.

Comment: `Also, this connector can only process the http log format created by Presto itself`. Maybe it's just me, but isn't the name "Local File Connector" a bit misleading? Maybe "Log File Connector" would have made clearer that it is not a "general purpose" connector.